# python, rebuilding lists

Tags: list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

trying to rebuild a list of lists containing coordinates.

what i got is

```
sel = ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0))
sel = [(1 - v[1]) for v in sel]
```

which is doing what i want to the 2nd coordinate in every set, but my problem is it returns as a list of values, not the list of lists with the 2nd value altered.

im doing this since the coordinate system for 2 different apps im working with is different. With one 0 is at the bottom of the way axis, and on the other which im trying to convert too 0 starts at the top of the y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, each element in your list comprehension is `(1-v[1])`, which is what you want to happen to the second value.  If you want each element to be a tuple where the first term in the tuple is the same as it used to be, but the second one is changed, you could do this:

```
>>> sel = ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0))
>>> sel = [(v[0], 1 - v[1]) for v in sel]
>>> sel
[(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

You could also avoid using indices, which can sometimes make for cleaner code (here it's about the same):

```
>>> sel = [(x, 1-y) for x,y in sel]
>>> sel
[(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```